# Draw multiple arrows using plotly python

Tags: plotly-python

There is an example about [multiple annotations](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/), it simply duplicate the go.layout.Annotation() to draw 2 arrows.

But I need to draw more than 100+ arrows, I don't know how.
The go.layout.Annotation() is tuple type and accepts dict() for each arrow, is there any easy way to add more dict() to tuple() ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved my own question.

fig.layout.annotations accepts list, parameters of each arrow is a dict(). So the idea is to create a list of many dict(), and then use fig.update_layout(annotations = list) to draw multiple arrows.

the dict() for each arrow looks like this:

```
arrow = go.layout.Annotation(dict(
                x= x_end,
                y= y_end,
                xref="x", yref="y",
                text="",
                showarrow=True,
                axref = "x", ayref='y',
                ax= x_start,
                ay= y_start,
                arrowhead = 3,
                arrowwidth=1.5,
                arrowcolor='rgb(255,51,0)',)
            )
```

the list for multiple arrows can be easily created like this:

```
list = list + [dict()]
```

Then, update the fig:

```
fig.update_layout(
annotations= list_of_all_arrows,)
```

If all arrows are in time series, this is the final result:
[image]

Comment: The problem of this method is that I had too many legends that I cannot easily turn on or turn off by one button.